# How to use libtorch from rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp, libtorch

How call I use a libtorch from R, in armadillo and Arrayfire there are libraries like RcppArmadillo/RcppArrayFire. Is there something equivalent for libtorch or there is another way to use it?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`torch` package](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/torch/index.html) which uses Rcpp to access torch?  If you have possible questions about extending it, maybe a better place to ask those question is theur repo?